# Angular PUT request - URL not found

Tags: angular

I am trying to update text through put request.

My HTML where new value to be update is gathered:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3" *ngFor ="let review of webService.review | async">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Review by {{ review.username }}
                    on {{ review.date | date }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ review.text }}
                    <br>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="text">
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ review.stars }} stars
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/reviews" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="onDelete()">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="editbtn" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- col -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

My function that is called when data is submitted

```js
    onEdit(){
        this.webService.editReview(this.text);
        console.log(this.text);
    }
```

My web.service.ts file

```js
editReview(reviewID) {
        let postData = new FormData();
        postData.append("text", this.text);

        return this.http.put(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies/' +
                this.movieID + '/reviews/' + this.reviewID, postData
                ).subscribe(response => {
                    console.log("Edit - Success");
                    }
                )
            }
```

Comment: subscribe to your service. `this.webService.editReview(this.text).subscribe(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: And what is the question/problem

Comment: @Sam he can't do that because he's already subscribed in his service, but agree, he should move the subscription to the ```component``` calling the service

Comment: I am getting a 404 Error

Comment: this is not angular error. this API level error because 404 means your put method is not available on API ? can you check the same

Comment: If you can't create simple stackblitz example, please open the console, go to the network tab and you will see all of the requests, please find and check the url of your request. I think the problem is the incorrect url

Comment: or please include the component and web.service logic parts which is connected with request. including the variables

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, please do the subscription and success/error handling in the component.

```js
    onEdit(){
        this.webService.editReview(this.text)
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log("Edit - Success");
            console.log(this.text);
        });  
     }

     //webservice part
     editReview(reviewID) {
        let postData = new FormData();
        postData.append("text", this.text);
        return this.http.put(
           'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies/' +
           this.movieID + '/reviews/' + this.reviewID, postData
        )
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Observables` need to be subscribed to start processing

```js
    onEdit(){
        this.webService.editReview(this.text).subscribe(console.log);
        console.log(this.text);
    }
```

and in service just return the Observable

```js
    editReview(reviewID) {
      let postData = new FormData();
      postData.append("text", this.text);

      return this.http.put(
          'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies/' +
                    this.movieID + '/reviews/' + this.reviewID, postData
                    )
    }
```

Comment: Made those changes and the error message I am receiving now reads: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.    in the HTML file

Comment: Please check the developer tools from where you are getting this error